# cannot install spaCy and textacy packages

Tags: pip, windows-10, spacy, python-3.7, textacy

cannot install spacy and textacy in python 3.7 in pip environment and windows 10

I tried to install spacy and textacy package but I received an error. I 
searched the error and I found that I need to install visual c++ toolkit 2017. so I did it. After that the error changed to a new one. I tried all the solution on the internet (clear pip cach, upgrade pip to last version, create path in windows environment, etc.) but still I cannot install these two packages.

pip install spaCy

the new error is:
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      msvc
      py_compiler msvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUn1z.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5gr0.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spaCy requires the 64-bit version of Python, but you're trying to install it with a 32-bit version. If you download the 64-bit version of Python and use that to install it, it should work.